# how to get specific nodes under unique keys in firebase realtime database android

Tags: java, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get data from nested nodes under unique keys. Each key is identical. It's difficult for me to deal with such problem help please.

I have tried ChildEventListener on database reference but not succeeded.

here is the code i am using to retreive data

InfoFragment.java

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Seller").getRef().child("ImpInfo");

    mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ShopSellerInfo shopSellerInfo = postDataSnapshot.getValue(ShopSellerInfo.class);
                mShopSellerInfo.add(shopSellerInfo);

            }
            mNearBySellerAdapter = new NearBySellerAdapter(getContext(), mShopSellerInfo);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNearBySellerAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    return rootView;`
```

ShopSellerInfo.java

```
public ShopSellerInfo(String shopAddress, String shopPhoneNo, String 
shopImageUrl, String shopName) {
    this.shopAddress = shopAddress;
    this.shopPhoneNo = shopPhoneNo;
    this.shopImageUrl = shopImageUrl;
    this.shopName = shopName;

}

public ShopSellerInfo() {

}


public String getShopAddress() {
    return shopAddress;
}


public String getShopPhoneNo() {
    return shopPhoneNo;
}

public String getShopImageUrl() {
    return shopImageUrl;
}

public String getShopName() {
    return shopName;
}

public void setUserAddress(String shopAddress) {
    this.shopAddress = shopAddress;
}

public void setUserPhoneNo(String shopPhoneNo) {
    this.shopPhoneNo = shopPhoneNo;
}

public void setImageUrl(String shopImageUrl) {
    this.shopImageUrl = shopImageUrl;
}

public void setShopName(String shopName) {
    this.shopName = shopName;
}
```

}

This is the structure of my Database

[image]

I have a specific node in each unique key the contain data. I want to retrieve that data form every child node and show on single activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not too far off, just a few mistakes. The following is closer to what you need:

```
mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Seller");

mFirebaseDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot sellerSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DataSnapshot impInfoSnapshot = sellerSnapshot.child("ImpInfo");
            ShopSellerInfo shopSellerInfo = impInfoSnapshot.getValue(ShopSellerInfo.class);
            mShopSellerInfo.add(shopSellerInfo);
            mNearBySellerAdapter = new NearBySellerAdapter(getContext(), mShopSellerInfo);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mNearBySellerAdapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
});
```

Changes:

- Removed the call to `.getRef()`, which is not needed and in general an anti-pattern.
- Removed the call to `.child("ImpInfo")` from the `DatabaseReference`, since there is no `/Seller/ImpInfo`.
- Added `.child("ImpInfo")` in the loop, since you want the `ImpInfo` child of each snapshot.
- Raise an error if `onCancelled` triggers, since it's a bad practice to ignore errors.

Comment: Thanks, sir it did work for me. looking forward to some more questions.